# Find an object in a list without iterating it

Tags: java, performance

I have a class with 3 properties:

```
private static class OrderListItem {
    public int price;
    public int size;
    public Type type;
}
```

Items of this class are added in a list. `List<OrderListItem> orders_book = new ArrayList<>();`

I want to find an object in a list with a specified price. But size and type do not matter. Can I do something like this:

`int index = orders_book.indexOf(new OrderListItem(price, **any size**, **any type**));` ?

Or I just must do a "loop" search?

Comment: You could use `stream()` or `forEach()` on the ArrayList if you don't want to use a literal `for` loop, although internally those do basically the same thing.

Comment: Well *something* is going to have to loop, whether that's in your code or `Stream` etc.

Comment: You could use `Stream` and `filter` and `findAny`

Comment: The `indexOf` method uses the objects equals method to determine its return result as stated in its documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object- So whether or not you can use `indexOf` depends on how your class implemented the `equals` method.

Comment: Is this a sorted array or a regular array?

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. A good name would be `orderedBook` for example. Only use "_" for SOME_CONSTANT. Other names are all camelCase or UpperCamelCase, depending on context.

Comment: What if multiple orders share some or all of those characteristics.  Wouldn't returning a list of matches be better.

Comment: Even if you could use `indexOf`, that is still looping over the list. Do you only search by price, never by size or type? You could maintain the list in ascending sorted order by price and do a binary search. Or maintain a map from price to (list of) order(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to retrieve an instance with a desired price, then you could use a collection stream with the `filter` and `findAny` operations.

```
int myPrice = /* any value you want */

//This will retrieve an instance with the disired price or null if none is found
OrderListItem item = orders_book.stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getPrice() == myPrice)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Alternatively, if you want to retrieve the index of the object with the desired price, then you have two options:

1. Redefine the `equals` method of your `OrderListItem` class, to equal two  OrderListItems by their price, since the documentation of the `indexOf` method retrieves an element by its `equals` method. However, I wouldn't lean towards this solution, as in my opinion the sole price is not enough to equal two order items, but you definitely know better than me the kind of problem you're modelling. So, I'll leave the choice to you. Furthermore, if you redefine the `equals` method you should also redefine the `hashCode` method as the general [hashcode contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) states.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

```
class OrderListItem {
    public int price;
    public int size;
    public Type type;

    /* ... your implementation ...*/

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(price);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        OrderListItem other = (OrderListItem) obj;
        return Objects.equals(price, other.price);
    }
}
```

2. Not redefining the equals method, but retrieving the exact instance with a stream (like in the first snippet) and then using that same instance as a parameter for the `indexOf` invocation.

```
int myPrice = /* any value you want */

//This will retrieve an instance with the disired price or null if none is found
OrderListItem item = orders_book.stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getPrice() == myPrice)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);

//Retrieving the index
int index = orders_book.indexOf(item);
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer! That's what I was looking for. Will this solution have any gain in speed against a simple loop iterating?

Comment: No, it should be slightly slower if anything, although this type of "early optimization" I think is bad to worry about as long as the code is clean and readable.

Comment: @markspace thanks. I need to optimize my code but it seems I am looking in a wrong side.

Comment: @Laughing_Man as markspace has already said, a traditional loop will be more efficient than streaming a collection, however the difference is minimal, especially for small collections. In my opinion, as markspace has also said, the code should be readable first if the difference in terms of efficiency are irrelevant.

Comment: You probably do not need to optimize the stream above.  It'll never show up on a real performance test.  Write the code, measure performance of a reasonably large chunk (not a micro-benchmark), *then* decide what to optimize.

Comment: Except for `set` and `map` lookups which are `hash based`, any method you can find in the API will ultimately use a loop or iterator of some sort (even streams).  So in some ways you are adding overhead with the method call or calls.  In any event, don't worry about it and just do what makes sense and is easiest to maintain.  Don't worry about optimization (if it is a noticeable problem) until after your code is written.

Comment: If you are going to define `equals` so it only depends on `price`, you ***MUST*** also do the same for `hashCode`.

Comment: @DavidConrad good point, forgot to mention that. I'll add it! Thanks for letting me notice!

Answer (score 2):

I'm offering this answer as a possibility although it may exceed your actual requirements.  Using some pre-defined predicates it allows any number of matching, consecutive items to be returned in a List. An empty list will be returned if no match is found.

But first, if you want the index (and maybe the value of the object) you can do it like this with no modification of your class.

- this uses an `IntStream` to stream all possible indices.
- it maps the index and the object at that index into a `Map.entry`
- then it filters using the `value` of the `entry` against the desired attribute.
- and returns the first one encountered or an Entry with -1 and null. (`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` was used here to allow the null value)

```
int desiredPrice = 3;
Entry<Integer, OrderListItem> result = IntStream
        .range(0, orderList.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(i, orderList.get(i)))
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getPrice() == desiredPrice)
        .findFirst().orElse(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(-1,null));
```

To facilitate the demonstration the following `record` is used in lieu of a class definition.  A class can be directly substituted for this.  A Type enum is also provided.

```
enum Type {
    FICTION, TECHNICAL, BIOGRAPHY
}

private record OrderListItem(int getPrice, int getSize,
        Type getType) {
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s, %s]", getPrice, getSize,
                getType);
    }
}
```

Now define some predicates. Each takes an `orderListItem` object and a `Type`.  The comparison method (equals or == ) is dependent on the attribute type. This predicate and the desired attribute value will be supplied to a method as shown later.  Even though you are only interested in `price`, the others were easy enough to add.

```
static BiPredicate<OrderListItem, Integer> CHECK_PRICE =
        (order, val) -> order.getPrice() == val;

static BiPredicate<OrderListItem, Type> CHECK_TYPE =
        (order, val) -> order.getType().equals(val);

static BiPredicate<OrderListItem, Integer> CHECK_SIZE =
            (order, val) -> order.getSize() == val;
```

Some data

```
List<OrderListItem> orderList =
        ArrayList<>(List.of(new OrderListItem(3, 20, Type.FICTION),
                new OrderListItem(4, 20, Type.TECHNICAL),
                new OrderListItem(5, 20, Type.TECHNICAL),
                new OrderListItem(3, 30, Type.FICTION),
                new OrderListItem(4, 30, Type.FICTION),
                new OrderListItem(5, 30, Type.TECHNICAL),
                new OrderListItem(3, 40, Type.FICTION),
                new OrderListItem(4, 40, Type.BIOGRAPHY),
                new OrderListItem(5, 40, Type.FICTION),
                new OrderListItem(3, 50, Type.FICTION),
                new OrderListItem(4, 50, Type.BIOGRAPHY),
                new OrderListItem(5, 50, Type.BIOGRAPHY)));
```

Demo

```
List<OrderListItem> matches =
        retrieve(orderList, CHECK_SIZE, 20, 2);
    
matches.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[3, 20, FICTION]
[4, 20, TECHNICAL]
```

The method takes the following arguments.

- the order list
- the predicate for comparison
- the attribute value to compare to
- the desired return count of successful matches (a negative value will result in all matches being returned).

The method works by simple iteration over the orders, applying the predicate to the order and attribute.  If a match is found, it is added to the return list and the count is decremented. When the count reaches `0` or the entire list is checked, the list will be returned.

```
public static <T> List<OrderListItem> retrieve(
        List<OrderListItem> orders,
        BiPredicate<OrderListItem, T> pred, T attribute,
        int count) {
    List<OrderListItem> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (OrderListItem order : orders) {
        if (pred.test(order, attribute)) {
            matches.add(order);
            if (--count == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

**Performance**

Not the best test as compared to JMH but a rough idea.

- First I added the data list to itself 20 times to create a large list.
- The I repeated the above lookup for all records sans the printout.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    orderList.addAll(orderList);
}
System.out.printf("%,d total objects%n",orderList.size());
    
long time = System.nanoTime();
List<OrderListItem> matches =
        retrieve(orderList, CHECK_SIZE, 20, -1);
System.out.println("Execution time ~ "+(System.nanoTime()-time)/1e9 + " sec");
```

prints

```
12,582,912 total objects
Execution time ~ 0.632698253 sec
```

With no matches found for the entire list, the result was
`Execution time ~ 0.033943752 sec.`

For matching the entire list the result was
`Execution time ~ 0.939900075 sec.`

The difference in time is mostly due (imo) to the backing array having to be updated as the capacity is increased.  This requires several recopyings of the array.  By setting the initial capacity of the returned list to `orders.size()`, the result for matching and returning all elements is improved.

For matching the entire list with adjusted capacity the result was `Execution time ~ 0.19100866 sec`

I'm running Windows on an Intel 4 core, I7 processor.

I have no idea how any of the above relates to your requirements but its there for your edification.